# use nodeJS module without nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox-addon-webextensions

it can look like a very simple question, but as a JS beginner, I would like to know if it was possible to use a NodeJS module (I would like to use this one for exemple : https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto) in a webextension without having to change it's code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since such a Node.js module depends on the Node.js runtime library, your only chance may be to [browserify](http://browserify.org). If that won't work, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of [xml-crypto](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto). xml-crypto is built for node.js and relies on the node.js crypto built in module which is not available for browsers. However there is an alternative browser crypto module called [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge). Someone told me they were able to replace xml-crypto dependency in crypto with forge (by making small code changes in xml-crypyo) and that allows to run xml-crypto in a browser. You would also need to use browserify which should be easy here.